# Using timer to run application inside NUNIT

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

In Nunit as part of test I have to start an application let it run for i.e 1 min than stop it and next it reads results from file and asserts if values are correct. I can start and stop the application using Process.Start("app.exe"); however I am not sure how to keep it running for x seconds inside the [Test]. Any idea how to go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Test]
void TestFiles()
{
    using(var process = Process.Start("app.exe"))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        process.Kill();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    // Check your files now
}
```

Comment: If I use Thread.Sleep(10000) when the process app.exe is started. Will it also stop the application during 10 seconds the Thread is sleeping? because I have to make the application keep running for that long before killing. Thanks

Comment: The process is running on its own thread - it will keep running in the background while the test thread is sleeping.

Comment: You may also want to use `WaitForExit` after `Kill`. `Kill` is asynchronous.